# Combine multiple CSVs, skip first 9 rows for each file

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, rows

In my jupyter notebook I am usually able to combine multiple .csv format files in a shared folder into one .csv with the following code that I did not originally write.

I now have files that have 9 rows of header/material that I want to omit, but don't know how to make it work with this format.  The files are pretty big individually as well.

How can I combine all the .csv files together and remove the 9 preceding rows?
Thanks for the help!

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd 
import csv

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])

#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Perhaps start off my reading the docs for the `read_csv` function (again?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv` takes an argument `skiprows`.

> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.

E.g.,

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=9) for f in all_filenames ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I had tried skiprows before, to no luck, but I think I understand some of the issue better.  When running the latest I get an error Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 29 fields in line 18, saw 30.  What seems to be happening is because some columns have data in fewer fields (blanks) and the number it is looking for is set by what is read earlier it breaks and throws an error.